Unable to make a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04, 24.04, or 24.10 on a Dell Inspiron laptop
A bit of a crisis and would greatly appreciate help! I have a Dell Inspiron 11 3158 (3000 series 2-in-1) laptop (500 MB hard disk, 8 GB RAM) that was working quite well except that it was a bit slow. The laptop is 8 years old. Since the RAM could not be upgraded further, I followed the advice of the Service Center and changed the hard disk to a new 1 TB SSD disk with no operating system preinstalled.
I have been trying to do a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop versions but the installations simply hang as described below. [I had Ubuntu 22.04 on the earlier hard disk and if I plug the old one back now (as an external HDD) then the laptop continues to boot successfully into Ubuntu 22.04 and all my files are still evident.]
For the fresh install, I used the official ISOs for Ubuntu 22.04, 24.04 and 24.10, but they all hang at a similar point. I first verified the ISOs (checksums) and then used Startup Disk Creator to create a bootable USB disk to start the fresh installation.
Whether I start on 'Legacy' boot (which is how it was with the old hard disk) or UEFI boot in the BIOS, the installation runs a little and hangs at the line that reads:
/usr/sbin/plymouthd(_start+0x25) [0x5c9ece2c0fc5]

as in the screenshot below.

I have tried installation with 'Safe Graphics' or by removing quiet splash or changing that to nomodeset as suggested in some other cases, but none of these worked.
Other system details:
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30 GHZ
64-Bit Technology: Yes (Intel EM64T)
I would greatly appreciate pointers on how to get past this bug/installation problem and get Ubuntu 22.04 (at least) back on the new hard disk. Also should I boot 'Legacy' or 'UEFI'?

Try this:
PC setup UEFI
Start a live session of Ubuntu 24.04 (NO 24.10).
Once the boot is complete, open a terminal and run:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gparted
sudo gparted

From gparted, select the hard drive.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a new gpt partition table.
In the free space, create a 512-megabyte partition, Efi-Boot partition (Fat32).
Next, create a 100-gigabyte partition, ext4 system.
Create another 16-gigabyte partition, swap system (24-gigabyte if you plan to hibernate.)
Create another remaining partition that you plan to use for Linux, ext4 system.
Apply the changes.
Close gparted.
Close the terminal.
Start the installation.
Choose manual partitioning and select:
Grub by default on the hard drive.
The 100-gigabyte partition for /
The 16 / 24-gigabyte partition for swap.
And the remaining one for /home.
Continue with the installation.

Thank you. I could get to Terminal and run sudo gparted... but it just showed the 1 TB HDD and a rotating wheel over it and I could not create new partitions (options greyed out).

You need to unmount it: sudo umount /dev/whatever. Delete the partition table if it exists and create a new gpt partition table.

Thank you @kyodake I'd earlier tried after unmounting only and it still didn't work. Update now is that I booted into Ubuntu 22.04 using the old external hard disk and then formatted the internal SSD disk as ext4 first using the Disks utility. Then I reran the installation from USB disk as a minimal installation (also without connecting to network or downloading updates and third party drivers). The installation progressed, created partitions (erase disk and create partitions step) and started copying files. However, it's stuck now at  "Almost finished copying files" for 20 min or so.

Try another distribution:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/mx-linux/files/Final/Xfce/MX-23.4_x64.iso/download

Thanks... but I'm committed to using Ubuntu for various reasons. The stalled installation at "Almost finished copying files" failed eventually. I retried after a few hours and the minimal installation proceeded further to setting up system stage before stopping with a "Installation failed" message. Terminal window showed large rolling list of error messages. Still looking for help to resolve this.

Then try installing Ubuntu Server, if it installs and works, just install the desktop and the applications you want. Previously, from the session with the previous disk, create the necessary partitions.

Well, I managed to install Ubuntu 22.04 by adding "pci=noaer" [or] "pci=noaer pci=nomsi" [either option works] after "quiet splash" in the grub menu while installing. This basically suppresses the pcie errors on loop in the background and the entire installation took less than 10 minutes. I've been able to start using the laptop except that it now does not shut down/logout/restart from the menu. This appears to be a different error now and I will start a new post about it to seek help.

Adding "pci-noaer" to the grub menu followed by update grub as suggested here, helped fix the shutdown problem as well.

I had a similar problem. With 'Startup Disk Creator' I couldn't get even past the first menu before it hung up. With UnetBootin I got to the 'Try Ubuntu' menu and then nothing. So I installed Balena Etcher to burn the ISO and BOOM ! ... It worked perfectly and had zero issues. https://etcher.balena.io/  ..I recommend a 16gb USB drive.  The system-file is about 7gb on the drive. I hope this helps.
You asked should I boot 'Legacy' or 'UEFI'? I would go with UEFI if available, as it is a newer system and is allegedly more efficient. You could reset your BIOS-boot settings to default and go from there...
